# How to apply if condition after finding element with findelement command

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am finding one link text and on the basis of this will take the action. for e.g.: On Login page will check for "English" link. If it is present then I wanted to click on this else I will continue my flow. Then How I can do this in webdriver. 
`driver.findelement(By.linktext("English"));`
If above condition is true then will take further actions. Can you please help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Put it in a try catch block. If element is located it will click it. If not found, it will throw an exception. Catch that exception, log it, and continue your flow.

Answer (score 2):

What vivek is saying in his comment is true, this is the util method I use, you can define in your context what it means if the element exists but is not visible, i treat it as `false`

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By byLocator) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(byLocator);
        return true;
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```